# Save geofield programmatically in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, coordinates, geospatial, drupal-8

I have read in a lot of sources that I should use the `geofield_compute_values()` function when trying to programmatically save coordinates in Drupal.

However it does not work for me, that function is undefined in the Drupal 8.5.2 that I am using.

I've installed geofield using composer and I can use it as usual in the admin area and there are no problems with saving there.

Here are some examples I've tried with, the first example gives me `undefined function geofield_compute_values()` :

```
$geofield_data = geofield_compute_values([
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lon' => $lon,
], GEOFIELD_INPUT_LAT_LON);

$cbisProduct->set('field_koordinater', $geofield_data);
```

I have also tried this out with no successful result and no errors :

```
$geofield = [
    'geom' => "POINT (" . $lon . " " . $lat . ")",
    'geo_type' => 'point',
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lon' => $lon,
    'left' => $lon,
    'top' => $lat,
    'right' => $lon,
    'bottom' => $lat,
];

$cbisProduct->set('field_koordinater', $geofield);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to use the [geofield_compute_values()](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/geofield/tree/geofield.module?h=7.x-2.x#n409) function which was available in 7.x version, but not in 8.x

You should look into the `wkt_generator` service. i.e.

```
<?php $wktGenerator = \Drupal::service('geofield.wkt_generator'); ?>
```

I haven't tried this, but something like this should work:

```
<?php

$point = [
  'lat' => $request->get('lat'), 
  'lon' => $request->get('lon'),
];
$value = \Drupal::service('geofield.wkt_generator')->WktBuildPoint($point);

$node->field_koordinater->setValue($value);
```

Also, [WktGeneratorTest.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/geofield/tree/tests/src/Kernel/WktGeneratorTest.php?h=8.x-1.x) and [GeofieldItemTest.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/geofield/tree/tests/src/Kernel/GeofieldItemTest.php?h=8.x-1.x) files could be a good start to see how to use the service in your implementation.

Comment: If anyone finds this, DON'T CONFUSE `geolocation` and `geofield` as I did!
Geolocation fields are set like this: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/set-geolocation-field-programmatically-drupal-8-solved 
Geofields are set just as @osman stated in his answer – thank you for that!

Answer (score 3):

This function is not available in Drupal 8. You have to rely on the basic `GeofieldItem` class that extends `FieldItemBase`. Also, as mentioned by oman, you can use `WktGenerator` to easily build points, polygons, etc.

Here a working example. Let's say your have an entity `$cbisProduct` with a multivalued geofield `field_koordinater`, and you want to set the first item with arbitrary lat/lon coordinates :

```
// Get geofield item
$geofield = $cbisProduct->get('field_koordinater')->get(0);

// Generate a point [lat, lon]
$coord = ['45.909621', '6.127147'];
$point = \Drupal::service('geofield.wkt_generator')->WktBuildPoint($coord);

// Calling this function will compute values AND assign geodata to the field instance
$geofield->setValue($point);

// You can read the computed geodata from the field
$geodata = $geofield->getValue();
//dpm($geodata);

// Explicitly set field data (needed if $geofield is not a reference)
$cbisProduct->set('field_koordinater', [$geodata]);

// Save entity
$cbisProduct->save();
```

Under the hood, `GeofieldItem::setValue` calls another method responsible to directly assign the computed values to the field instance :

```
# \Drupal\geofield\Plugin\Field\FieldType\GeofieldItem
protected function populateComputedValues() {
  /* @var \Geometry $geom */
  $geom = \Drupal::service('geofield.geophp')->load($this->value);

  if (!empty($geom)) {
    /* @var \Point $centroid */
    $centroid = $geom->getCentroid();
    $bounding = $geom->getBBox();

    $this->geo_type = $geom->geometryType();
    $this->lon = $centroid->getX();
    $this->lat = $centroid->getY();
    $this->left = $bounding['minx'];
    $this->top = $bounding['maxy'];
    $this->right = $bounding['maxx'];
    $this->bottom = $bounding['miny'];
    $this->geohash = substr($geom->out('geohash'), 0, GEOFIELD_GEOHASH_LENGTH);
    $this->latlon = $centroid->getY() . ',' . $centroid->getX();
  }
}
```

Note : You don't necessarily need WktGenerator for building points, as long as you know the geofield type and how `geophp` should handle it. For example, the following 2 statements are equivalent :

```
$point = \Drupal::service('geofield.wkt_generator')->WktBuildPoint($coord);
// is equivalent to 
$point = GEOFIELD_TYPE_POINT . '(' . implode(' ', $coord) . ')');
```

But it is safer to rely on the WktGenerator especially with more complex data types.